# PIP3 Site-Packages Installation Path / Module not found : Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I think I messed up ! I have python3.8 is running ( confirmed from python3 --version). The sys.path has following

```
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I have installed packages via PIP3. PIP3 seems to be installing at

```
 ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.0.1)
```

I had python3.5 earlier which I removed and installed 3.8 . Since sys.path does not the above site-packages location the code does not find the module and gives me module not found error.

How do I fix it. I suspect I messed up during installation/upgrade of python at some point.

Edit: Did some more digging. When I run user site command I get this:

```
python3 -m site --user-site
/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

However Python3.8 folder does not exist. Only folder in local/lib is python3.5 which has site-packages under it. I am at a loss here . Any help would is appreciated.

Comment: can you run `which pip3`? what is the path?

Comment: /home/myusername/.local/bin/pip3